# Specifying column names from a list in the data.frame command

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a list called `cols` with column names in it:

`cols <- c('Column1','Column2','Column3')`

I'd like to reproduce this command, but with a call to the list:

`data.frame(Column1=rnorm(10))`

Here's what happens when I try it:

`> data.frame(cols[1]=rnorm(10))`

`Error: unexpected '=' in "data.frame(I(cols[1])="`

The same thing happens if I wrap `cols[1]` in `I()` or `eval()`.

How can I feed that item from the vector into the `data.frame()` command?

**Update:**

For some background, I have defined a function `calc.means()` that takes a data frame and a list of variables and performs a large and complicated ddply operation, summarizing at the level specified by the variables.

What I'm trying to do with the `data.frame()` command is walk back up the aggregation levels to the very top, re-running `calc.means()` at each step and using `rbind()` to glue the results onto one another. I need to add dummy columns with 'All' values in order to get the rbind to work properly.

I'm rolling `cast`-like margin functionality into ddply, basically, and I'd like to not retype the column names for each run. Here's the full code:

```
cols <- c('Col1','Col2','Col3')
rbind ( calc.means(dat,cols),
    data.frame(cols[1]='All', calc.means(dat, cols[2:3])),
    data.frame(cols[1]='All', cols[2]='All', calc.means(dat, cols[3]))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use can use `structure`:

```
cols <- c("a","b")

foo <- structure(list(c(1, 2 ), c(3, 3)), .Names = cols, row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I don't get why you are doing this though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it directly, but you could simply skip the step of assigning names in the data.frame() command. Assuming you store the result of data.frame() in a variable named foo, you can simply do:

names(foo) <- cols

after the data frame is created

Comment: Yes, this would normally work, but the `data.frame()` happens inside an `rbind()`. Thanks, though.

Comment: You could create the data frame, assign the column names, and then rbind them, all in one clause.

Comment: Shane,
How would that work? I'm not sure how to pass the objects through the process in a single clause.

Answer (score 1):

There is one trick. You could mess with lists:

```
cols_dummy <- setNames(rep(list("All"), 3), cols)
```

Then if you use call to list with **one** paren then you should get what you want

```
data.frame(cols_dummy[1], calc.means(dat, cols[2:3]))
```

You could use it on-the-fly as `setNames(list("All"), cols[1])` but I think it's less elegant.

Example:

```
some_names <- list(name_A="Dummy 1", name_B="Dummy 2") # equivalent of cols_dummy from above
data.frame(var1=rnorm(3), some_names[1])
#        var1  name_A
# 1 -1.940169 Dummy 1
# 2 -0.787107 Dummy 1
# 3 -0.235160 Dummy 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the assign() function is your answer:

```
cols <- c('Col1','Col2','Col3')
data.frame(assign(cols[1], rnorm(10)))
```

Returns:

```
   assign.cols.1...rnorm.10..
1                 -0.02056822
2                 -0.03675639
3                  1.06249599
4                  0.41763399
5                  0.38873118
6                  1.01779018
7                  1.01379963
8                  1.86119518
9                  0.35760039
10                 1.14742560
```

With the lapply() or sapply() function, you should be able to loop the cbind() process. Something like:

```
operation <- sapply(cols, function(x) data.frame(assign(x, rnorm(10))))
final     <- data.frame(lapply(operation, cbind))
```

Returns:

```
   Col1.assign.x..rnorm.10.. Col2.assign.x..rnorm.10.. Col3.assign.x..rnorm.10..
1                0.001962187                -0.3561499               -0.22783816
2               -0.706804781                -0.4452781               -1.09950505
3               -0.604417525                -0.8425018               -0.73287079
4               -1.287038060                 0.2545236               -1.18795684
5                0.232084366                -1.0831463                0.40799046
6               -0.148594144                 0.4963714               -1.34938144
7                0.442054119                 0.2856748                0.05933736
8                0.984615916                -0.0795147               -1.91165189
9                1.222310749                -0.1743313                0.18256877
10              -0.231885977                -0.2273724               -0.43247570
```

Then, to clean up the column names:

```
colnames(final) <- cols
```

Returns:

```
          Col1       Col2        Col3
1   0.19473248  0.2864232  0.93115072
2  -1.08473526 -1.5653469  0.09967827
3  -1.90968422 -0.9678024 -1.02167873
4  -1.11962371  0.4549290  0.76692067
5  -2.13776949  3.0360777 -1.48515698
6   0.64240694  1.3441656  0.47676056
7  -0.53590163  1.2696336 -1.19845723
8   0.09158526 -1.0966833  0.91856639
9  -0.05018762  1.0472368  0.15475583
10  0.27152070 -0.2148181 -1.00551111
```

Cheers,

Adam